# Iterating over datasets to update column in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Hopefully you can help me with a database problem that I'm struggling with :)

Suppose I have a table as following:

```
id  |  user_id  |  training_id  | date                |  performance  |  best
1   |  7042     |  11           | 2013-07-23 13:43:29 |  654          |  true
2   |  7042     |  11           | 2013-07-25 15:22:59 |  703          |  false
3   |  2344     |  12           | 2013-07-26 09:20:12 |  400          |  true
...
```

The table contains trainings (training_id) that a user (user_id) has absolved. When a user absolves a training with better performance than all previous trainings of that kind (training_id) he has a best (best = true). I now want to add an auxiliary column 'last_best' so that I can query for the last best of each training for a given user. To provide the values for missing last_pb I want to run a script over all trainings in the database.

My first approach was to iterate over all trainings and users in rails console. However this approach is really slow. It would take around 36 hours for a dataset of about 70.000 users and 200.000 trainings.

Now I want to do the same with SQL, but I'm struggling with iterating over users and trainings.
Hope you can help me there.

Comment: When you say "When a user absolves a training with better performance than all previous trainings of that kind (training_id) he has a best (best = true)" do you mean for each user or across all users?

Comment: I mean for each user separately (he set a new record for his trainings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query does a ranking in MySQL using variables:

```
select t.*,
       @rn := if(@user_id <> USER_ID or @training_id <> training_id, @rn + 1, 1) as ranking,
       @user_id := user_id,
       @training_id := training_id
from t cross join
     (select @user_id := -1, @training_id := -1, @rn := 0) const
order by USER_ID, training_id, performance desc;
```

This is undoubtedly the most efficient method for what you want to do.  A word of caution.  Although it works in practice, there is an issue.  MySQL does not guarantee the ordering of evaluation of arguments.  The query depends on `ranking` being evaluated before the two variable assignments.  In practice, they are evaluated in order, but this is not guaranteed.